# Upload Stream Requests and UIProgressView, Swift 3

Tags: swift3, nsurlsession, uiprogressview

I would like to track the progress of videos uploaded through a stream request with a UIProgressView.  Unfortunately, I am not using Alamofire, so I'm not sure if URLSession has this ability.  Below is relevant code from my application.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {

    let uploadProgress:Float = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
    let uploadCell = contentTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! NewContentCell
    uploadCell.uploadProgressView.progress = uploadProgress


}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    let uploadCell = contentTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! NewContentCell
    uploadCell.uploadProgressView.progress = 1.0
}
```

`didCompleteWithError` correctly sets the UIProgressView to indicate that the upload is complete, however, `didSendBodyData` is returning values greater than 1 through the `uploadProgress` calculation.

It's my first time utilizing a stream request, so I'm hoping I simply glossed over something that you could help point out.  Here is the structure of my request as well for reference.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "\(requestUrl)")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBodyStream = InputStream(data: body as Data)

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let dataTask = session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request as URLRequest)
        dataTask.resume()
```

Much thanks for your input and help.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64)
```

is the correct way to track stream request progression.

But if you want to now the `totalBytesExpectedToSend`, you must tell it to the server. So don't forget to set the correct `Content-Length` header in your request!

Here's the way i'm creating the request:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/octet-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(String(dataToUpload.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length") // <-- here!
request.httpBodyStream = InputStream(data: dataToUpload)
var task = session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request)
task?.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading documentation further, figured out that stream objects do not support `totalBytesExpectedToSend`.  It may be a hack, but just using the file's `NSData.length` feature allows for correct progress tracking.  So for stream requests using URLSession, progress can be tracked by using `didSendBodyData`, with `let uploadProgress: Float = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(mediaSize)`, where `mediaSize` is `NSData.length`.

Comment: how did you track you stream progression? `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64)` is never called on stream tasks!

Comment: Ooops. I just forgot to call `streamTask.resume()`